# catkin_make error after creating custom message

Tags: ros, add-message-files

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after creating a custom messages files .msg under /mypackage/msg/ when i run the `catkin_make` i git this error

```
 Messages depends on unknown pkg: geometry_msgs (Missing
 find_package(geometry_msgs?))
```

even after uncommented this in the Cmake file

```
## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs std_msgs
 )
```

note when i run the command `rospack find  geometry_msgs` 
i got this  `/opt/ros/indigo/share/geometry_msgs`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230223/catkin_make-error-after-creating-custom-message/) by [g-emad](https://answers.ros.org/users/26155/g-emad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're probably missing some things in your `CMakeLists.txt` and / or `package.xml`. See [catkin 0.6.18 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) » Building messages, services or actions](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_msgs.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [g-emad](https://answers.ros.org/users/26155/g-emad/) on 2016-03-27**:
i will check again